# React dynamically create buttons based on number of results

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, web

I am working in a Spring application that uses react. Currently I have a json that contains several users based on certain criteria. The number of users can vary, but I would like to create several buttons for each user returned that links to the users profile. the url is just '/profile/username'

format of json

```
[{"user":{"principal":"cat@sitter.com","schedule":null,"appointments":null,"roles":["ROLE_USER"],"attributes":{"principal":"cat@sitter.com","zipcode":"98077","firstname":"cat","password":"abc123","sitterFlag":"true","ownerFlag":"false","lastname":"sitter","username":"catsitter","preferredPet":"Cat"},"momento":"cat@sitter.com"},"password":"$2a$10$ltnL.mFqo7hatj69Ls76xeegjhEX0D4At9m1rlBHbQtDrV8MdSeAS","momento":"cat@sitter.com"},{"user":{"principal":"test@pets.com","schedule":null,"appointments":null,"roles":["ROLE_USER"],"attributes":{"principal":"test@pets.com","zipcode":"98077","firstname":"test","password":"abc123","sitterFlag":"false","ownerFlag":"false","lastname":"pets","username":"testpets"},"momento":"test@pets.com"},"password":"$2a$10$wDhS6Mb8syhC0YIqgVG2qu8J6lA.1T.UprMYwAX6O7Xb3YMhgX3bO","momento":"test@pets.com"},{"user":{"principal":"test@sitter.com","schedule":null,"appointments":null,"roles":["ROLE_USER"],"attributes":{"principal":"test@sitter.com","zipCode":"98077","firstname":"test","password":"abc123","lastname":"sitter","username":"testsitter"},"momento":"test@sitter.com"},"password":"$2a$10$DuIeWFSzhtAjX3lr8xBNiu2kV9kAJ/PQ6pB/EzkB7FkGWfRbwxkzy","momento":"test@sitter.com"},{"user":{"principal":"sit@sitter.com","schedule":null,"appointments":null,"roles":["ROLE_USER"],"attributes":{"principal":"sit@sitter.com","zipCode":"98077","firstname":"sit","password":"abc123","lastname":"sitter","username":"imasitter"},"momento":"sit@sitter.com"},"password":"$2a$10$2NKOQkGZO/jUer3UjNGzdugUhkMV1pJ1eT8NQjSPRto9/cRdm56sO","momento":"sit@sitter.com"},{"user":{"principal":"a@sitter.com","schedule":null,"appointments":null,"roles":["ROLE_USER"],"attributes":{"principal":"a@sitter.com","zipCode":"98077","firstname":"a","password":"abc123","lastname":"sitter","username":"asitter"},"momento":"a@sitter.com"},"password":"$2a$10$8x1uVqR28x5rwNrydieSyu1ILifBJ5n0dUsZI5tJ6MoUWMqXxrmeq","momento":"a@sitter.com"}]
```

I currently have it working if I hard code for each user:

```
<div className="container padded">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-6 offset-md-3">
            <h2>Suggested Sitters</h2>
            <button onClick={() => this.suggestSitter(this.props.user.principal)}>Click</button>
            <hr/>
            <div>
                Sitters:
            </div>
            <Link to={this.setProfile(this.state.sitter ? this.state.sitter[1].user.attributes.username: ' ')} >
                <button type="button">{this.state.sitter ? this.state.sitter[1].user.attributes.username: ' '}</button>
            </Link>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the setProfile works like this:

```
setProfile(theUser) {
    return '/profile/' + theUser;
}
```

Clicking a button will redirect to that user's profile page.

So basically, instead of hardcoding n buttons, I would like to dynamically create n buttons and each will link to '/profile/username/ for each user returned.

suggestSitter function:

```
suggestSitter(user){
        var _this = this;
        console.log('user', user);
        axios.get('/api/user/suggest_sitter', { params: { principal: user } })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                _this.setState({
                    sitter: response
                });
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                console.log('Error: ' + e);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the data to an array of `Link` (provide an unique key for it too):

```
{this.state.sitter.map((e) => (
  <Link key={e.someUniqueProperty} to={this.setProfile(e.user.attributes.username)}>
    <button type="button">{e.user.attributes.username}</button>
  </Link>
))}
```

Comment: Some unique property in your data, eg. user's id/username. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys. If there's nothing unique in the data (unlikely) then just use the index `map((e, i) => ... key={i}`.

Comment: where does e get initialized? i included the suggest sitter function in the question, is it the same e from that?

Comment: `e` is an element in the `this.state.sitter` array, so if it's an array of users then `e` is an user. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.

Comment: I just copied your code segment and placed it where i was originally creating the buttons deleting "<Link to={this.setProfile(this.state.sitter ? this.state.sitter[1].user.attributes.username: ' ')} >
                <button type="button">{this.state.sitter ? this.state.sitter[1].user.attributes.username: ' '}</button>
            </Link>" and I created the unique key. however it still isn't working. Am i missing something?

Comment: Does it show anything or any errors? Does `console.log(this.state.sitter)` give you the json you posted above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169734/discussion-between-jakeeln-and-riwu).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your data is:

```
const data = [
  {user: {...}, attribute: {...}},
  {user: {...}, attribute: {...}},
  ...
]
```

Now, you can follow these steps:

Create a stateless/stateful component(depending on your use case): `UserButton` or any other meaningful name:

```
const UserButton = () => (
    <div className="container padded">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-6 offset-md-3">
                /*...Add your remaining JSX....*/
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Now in your parent component(from where you are actually rendering the data), you can do the following:

```
renderUserButtons = () => {
    return data.map((userData) => (
        <UserButton key="Some-unique-id-can-be-anything" PASS_YOUR_PROPS_HERE/>
    ))
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            {this.renderUserButtons()}
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

Obviously, you don't need multiple components for this, but splitting it into smaller components looks good, easier to maintain and easier to test. Again it's my personal preference. You can use the convention whatever is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

To create any UI component from some array, you can always use map function like below.

Array of JSON Object

```
let users = [{"name":"ABC"},{"name":"DEF"},{"name":"GHI"}];
```

Map Function

```
let userList = users.map((user,index)=>{return (<div>{index} - {user.name}<div>)})
```

this will give you following output:

0 - ABC
1 - DEF
2 - GHI

in map function user is the reference to one by one users from the array. Index is the key for each value from array (ex. 0,1,2....).

We are returning a JSX object from the return statement.

You can now use userList variable in render's return. Like below..

```
render(){ let userList = "...."; return(<div>{userList}</div>
```

I hope this would help.